# boolean will not return false

Tags: java, boolean

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HiLo {

/**
 * Nick Jones
 * 2/10/2015
 * High or Low
 */
public static boolean high()   {
    int x;
    boolean answer;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    x = randomGenerator.nextInt(9 - 1) + 1;
    System.out.println("number is " + x);

if (x > 6 && x < 14) {
    System.out.println("You win!");
    answer = true;
    return answer;
} else {
    System.out.println("You lose!");
    answer = false;
    return answer;
}
}


public static boolean low()   {
    int x;
    boolean answer;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    x = randomGenerator.nextInt(9 - 1) + 1;
    System.out.println("number is " + x);

    if (x > 0 && x < 7) {
        System.out.println("You win!");
        answer = true;
        return answer;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You lose!");
        answer = false;
        return answer;
    }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int points = 1000;
    int risk;
    int guess;
    boolean answer;
    int again;

    do {
    System.out.println("you have " + points + " points.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Input number of points to risk:  ");
    risk = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("predict <1-high, 0-low>:  ");
    guess = input.nextInt();

    if (guess == 1) {
        answer = high();
    } if (guess == 0) {
        answer = low();
    }

    if (answer = true) {
        points = points + (risk*2);
    **} if (answer = false) {
        points = points - risk;**
    }
    System.out.println("You have " + points + " points.");

    System.out.println("play again?<yes-1, no-0>  ");
    again = input.nextInt();

    } while (again == 1);





}

}
```

This program is meant to start with the player having a score of 1000 points a number is then randomly generated and they chose a amount of their score to 'risk' then chose high or low (low - 1-6. high - 8-13) if their guess is correct their risk is doubled and added back into their score. If incorrect then risk is subtracted from score. my boolean statment seems to be stopping the program from

```
if (answer = false) {
    points = points - risk;
```

this part, so my boolean never returns false is what I believe my problem is. because when run it only ever allows the player to win, never to lose, it will output that 'you lose' but still add the points as if they had won.

Comment: Just to add more to what @rgettman said... when using a single `=`, that is an assigment operator. Meaning, you were just assigning `answer` to always be true. When comparing values like that, you would use `==`, but since this is a `boolean`, you don't need that. You just provide the boolean in the if-statement as is and Java handles it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=`, so `answer` is always `true`.  The comparison operator for equality is `==`, as you have already used elsewhere in your code.  But `answer` is already a boolean.  There is no need to use `==` to compare it; just use it.  Change

```
if (answer = true) {
    points = points + (risk*2);
} if (answer = false) {
    points = points - risk;
}
```

to

```
if (answer) {
    points = points + (risk*2);
} else {
    points = points - risk;
}
```

Comment: if downvoting, at least provide a reason why

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain how this post can be improved.

Comment: @rgettman I am not down-voter but you can improve this post by explaining that `==` is used for comparison. Also OP may not be experience with boolean logic enough to see why `foo==true` is same as `foo`. Another thing you can add is how to handle case with `!=`.

Comment: @Pshemo I will add an explanation about `==`, but I didn't originally think it was necessary.  The OP did use `==` properly in the `if` statements about `guess` just above the `if` statements about `answer` and in the do-while condition at the bottom.

Comment: I am not saying that it is necessary, I am saying it would be improvement :)